# What are the best resources for me to learn more on Metro UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, microsoft-metro

i want to implement a website with Metro UI. What are the best resources for me to learn more on Metro UI framework?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that one of the best places to start are :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/hh779072

or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This kind of question is best reserved for Google. StackOverflow is more of a brainstorming site for already attempted ideas, not really a place to start-from-scratch.

To learn more on Metro UI, visit http://metroui.org.ua/.

I also heard that http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/ is a good site to start learning.